# How if a string is located ANYWHERE in another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know similar questions have been asked but before you down vote, hear me out.

If I want to check lets say if the string "Daniel" is located anywhere in "danielrydg123" ignoring capitals (should return true if the second string was "Danielrydg123" or "danielrydg123") how would I do this?

Comment: `str_a.lower() in str_b.lower()`

Answer (score 3):

```
if "Daniel".lower() in "Danielrydg123".lower():
    print("found it")
```

Output:

> found it

I suggest you review [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp)

Additionally you can use `.find()` as @Bucket has pointed out, which would translate into an `if` statement like:

```
if "Danielrydg123".lower().find("Daniel".lower()) >= 0:
    print("found it")
```

Output:

> found it

Answer (score 2):

User `find()`

```
str1 = "123Danielrydg123"
str2 = "noPe"
sub = "daniel"
str1.lower().find(sub) # returns 3
str2.lower().find(sub) # returns -1
```